# Dateutil recognizing the date but returning incorrect year (always the current year instead)

Tags: python, date, datetime

Basically what I'm trying to do is recognize when there is a date in a string, then replace whatever format the date is in with a standardized format. So the input is a string with an unformatted date, and the output is the same string but with a formatted date replacing the original. The problem is that it doesn't seem to be recognizing years correctly, even though it is definitely identifying the years as part of the date in the old string.  It seems to only be a problem if the date is in the format of *month day, year*. Any suggestions??

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

old_str1 = 'of these founders, who held his governmental position since March 3, 1795?'
old_str2 = 'of these founders, who held his governmental position since March 3, 1995?'

def convert_date_in_string(old_str):
    try:
        new_date, excl_str = dparser.parse(old_str, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
        new_date = str(new_date)[:10]
    
        excl_str = list(excl_str)
        excl_str.sort(reverse=True,key = len)
        old_date = old_str
        for i in excl_str:
            if i != ' ':
                old_date = old_date.replace(i,'')
        print(old_date)

    except:
        new_str = old_str
    return(new_str)

new_str1 = convert_date_in_string(old_str1)
new_str2 = convert_date_in_string(old_str2)

print(new_str1)
print(new_str2)
```

**outputs**:

old dates:

March 3, 1795

March 3, 1995

new strings:

of these founders, who held his governmental position since **2022-03-03**?

of these founders, who held his governmental position since **2022-03-03**?

Comment: I'd clearly put this in the category of it-can't-magically-find-any-and-all-freeform-date-formats…? If you expect dates of this specific format, look for them with specific regexen. Otherwise it's up to whatever dateutil happens to detect, which may be entirely faulty.

Comment: `parser` parses `"March 3, 1795"` with no issues. But fails with the string you are using. So, as mentioned in the first comment, you will need some pre-processing of the string. For example, the long string seems to work if the `?` is removed.

Comment: for finding dates in strings, [datefinder](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be the better option.